# Questions of using CocoaAsyncSocket to read socket data

Tags: objective-c, macos, sockets, binary-data, cocoaasyncsocket

I got the framework from [CocoaAsyncSocke gibhub](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) to read socket data from a server,but i can't read the correct jpg content,  Can some one tell me what wrong in my code?

The frame binary format of the socket.
[binary format][2]

```
 - (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket * __nonnull)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString * __nonnull)host port:(uint16_t)port
{
    NSLog(@"connect to host:%@ %d",host,port);

    [sock readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];
}
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket * __nonnull)sock didReadData:(NSData * __nonnull)data withTag:(long)tag
{
    NSInteger len = data.length;

//    Byte *byteArray = (Byte *)[data bytes];

//    for (int i=0 ; i<[data length]; i++) {
//        NSLog(@"-----row =%d  and byte = %d",i,byteArray[i]);
//    }

    if (tag == 0) {


        NSLog(@"tag 0:data:%@ len:%ld",data,data.length);
        [data writeToFile:@"/tmp/t.png" atomically:YES];

        [sock readDataToLength:4 withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"data:%@ len:%ld %@",data,data.length,data);

        UInt32 readLength;
        [data getBytes:&readLength length:4];
        [sock readDataToLength:readLength withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
    }
}
```

Comment: How does JPEG data enter into it?  You haven't given us nearly enough information to help you.  How is the host serving the data? Is it actually JPEG data?  How do you know?

Comment: David, I post a link of the socket frame named 'binary format‘.

Comment: we have got the image data in windows app with C#, now we need to update in our Mac app.

Comment: confirm your socket code by sending a short block of plain text.